# Update column with correct daterange using generate_series

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I have a column with incorrect dateranges (a day is missing). The code
to generate these dateranges was written by a previous employee and
cannot be found.

The dateranges look like this, notice the missing day:

```
+-------+--------+-------------------------+ 
|  id   | client |       date_range        |
+-------+--------+-------------------------+ 
| 12885 |     30 | [2016-01-07,2016-01-13) | 
| 12886 |     30 | [2016-01-14,2016-01-20) |
| 12887 |     30 | [2016-01-21,2016-01-27) | 
| 12888 |     30 | [2016-01-28,2016-02-03) | 
| 12889 |     30 | [2016-02-04,2016-02-10) |
| 12890 |     30 | [2016-02-11,2016-02-17) | 
| 12891 |     30 | [2016-02-18,2016-02-24) |
+-------+--------+-------------------------+
```

And should look like this:

```
+-------------------------+ 
|          range          |
+-------------------------+ 
| [2016-01-07,2016-01-14) | 
| [2016-01-14,2016-01-21) | 
| [2016-01-21,2016-01-28) | 
| [2016-01-28,2016-02-04) | 
| [2016-02-04,2016-02-11) | 
| [2016-02-11,2016-02-18) | 
| [2016-02-18,2016-02-25) | 
| [2016-02-25,2016-03-03) |
+-------------------------+
```

The code I've written to generate correct dateranges looks like this:

```
 create or replace function generate_date_series(startsOn date, endsOn date, frequency interval)
 returns setof date as $$
 select (startsOn + (frequency * count))::date
 from (
   select (row_number() over ()) - 1 as count
   from generate_series(startsOn, endsOn, frequency)
 ) series
 $$ language sql immutable;

 select DATERANGE(
   generate_date_series(
     '2016-01-07'::date, '2024-11-07'::date, interval '7days'
   )::date,
   generate_date_series(
     '2016-01-14'::date, '2024-11-13'::date, interval '7days'
   )::date
 ) as range;
```

However, I'm having trouble trying to update the column with the
correct dateranges. I initially executed this UPDATE query on a test
database I created:

```
update factored_daterange set date_range = dt.range from (  
 select daterange(
     generate_date_series(
       '2016-01-07'::date, '2024-11-07'::date, interval '7days'
     )::date,
     generate_date_series(
       '2016-01-14'::date, '2024-11-14'::date, interval '7days'
     )::date   ) as range ) dt where client_id=30;
```

But that is not correct, it simply assigns the first generated
 daterange to each row. I want to essentially update the dateranges
 row-by-row since there is no other join or condition I can match the
 dates up to. Any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working too hard. Just update the upper range value.

```
update your_table_name
   set date_range = daterange(lower(date_range),(upper(date_range) + interval '1 day')::date) ;
```

Comment: That's a much easier solution, guess I was overthinking it on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: Not uncommon, especially with ranges. If you like the solution please accept it.